# Perl : Strawberry perl Module Installation Failure

Tags: strawberry-perl

Attempting to do `cpan App::Ack` on windows

but getting the following errors

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/from_file.t   (Wstat: 3328 Tests: 10 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 13
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 17 tests but ran 10.
Files=16, Tests=74, 23 wallclock secs ( 0.30 usr +  0.09 sys =  0.39 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/16 test programs. 0/74 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:865: test_dynamic] Error 255
  PETDANCE/File-Next-1.16.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PETDANCE/File-Next-1.16.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'File::Next'.
```

Please help find a solution and get strawberry installed on windows, thanks.

Comment: OS - Windows 10 i am running the command cpanApp::Ack on commandline